# searching with haystack and xapian?

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack, xapian

I've been trying to do this search:

the post's title is 'help me'

in my code it's:

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(title=request.Get.copy()['search'])
```

so if I search 'help', 'me', or 'help me' I get the post, however if I search 'me help', I don't.  I want to search 'me help' and still get the post.  Or if a post's title is 'help me please' and I search 'help please', I'll still get the post...

So I searched a bit on stackoverflow... and reached a post here:
[Django + Haystack how to do this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157480/django-haystack-how-to-do-this-search)

I followed the accepted answer's two suggestions

however, when I did:

```
Change HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR within your settings.py to be OR.
```

when I search 'me help', I got all results, even those without 'help' or 'me'

when I did:

```
SearchQuerySet.filter_or(**kwargs)
```

nothing really changed, searching 'help', 'me', 'help me' worked, but 'me help' still didn't.

I'm sure the answer's obvious, but I new to haystack... So how do I get the query (searching 'me help') to get the post ('help me')?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the auto_query method? E.g

```
SearchQuerySet().auto_query(request.Get.copy()['search'])
```